# Shift + delete sends to trash for desktop files

Tags: delete, trash

I'm on Ubuntu 20.10. When I use shift+delete in the file manager, I get a confirmation dialog asking if I want to permanently delete the files, and if I click yes, they're permanently deleted.

*However*, if I shift+delete a file on the desktop, I get no confirmation dialog, and the file goes to trash.

Why is this behavior inconsistent? How can I make it consistent? I've Google'd a good bit, but all I've found is people saying to use shift+delete to delete permanently, which is what I'm already trying to do.

Comment: Ubuntu 20.10 (along with all flavors) is *End-of-Life* and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/06/18/ubuntu-20-10-groovy-gorilla-reaches-end-of-life-on-july-22-2021/ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades

Comment: @pLumo Yes, it appears so. I will give it a try. Thanks.

Comment: Anyways, you should update to 21.04 asap